# Why java String creates non-english characters like 'square'

Tags: java, arrays, json, string, character-encoding

When I try to assign my json result to a string value, it is not display non-english chars like: [image: here]

And here is my code;

```
            InputStream is  = connection.getInputStream();
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            IOUtils.copy(is, sw,"UTF-8");
            String s=sw.toString();
            JSONObject mainjobj= new JSONObject(s);
```

Is there anything wrong with my code ?

Comment: The problem isn't Java, the font used by Eclipse doesn't have the glyphs to display those characters, and therefor defaults to a square.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel so is there a solution for that ?

Comment: You could check the font configuration of Eclipse, maybe you can select a different font that has full unicode support.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Knowing the issue comes from Eclipse, does the "UTF-8" has any effect in this code ?

Comment: It's related as in it allows you to read unicode characters into a string, but not using UTF-8 would probably give you entirely wrong results (ie: wrong characters).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I updated all default fonts to UTF-8 but it still same and after IOUtils.copy process my sw still includes these 'squares', what you think it can be a problem on my code ?

Comment: No, the problem is not in your code (unless maybe you should be using a totally different encoding, which is not very likely), the problem is probably still that the font doesn't support the unicode glyphs you are trying to display (and note that fonts aren't "UTF-8").

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yes, I changed according to this link : https://z0ltan.wordpress.com/2011/12/25/changing-the-encoding-in-eclipse-to-utf-8-howto/

Comment: Are you sure the encoding you get from the `InputStream` is `UTF-8`?

Comment: Have u changed the Text file encoding in Eclipse ? **Window > Preferences >Workspace > Text file encoding**

Comment: @GoodBadandUgly yes I changed.

Comment: @Kayaman I think it is not, I mean when I look at it, it also includes 'squares' but if problem on the eclipse font, than It is normal to see that 'squares' I think

Comment: @user1798028 What are you expecting as the data? What language text?

Comment: @Kayaman the json result text includes burmese language

Comment: @user1798028 Save the bytes in a file and open it up with a text editor that allows you to select the encoding. Then find out which encoding it is by trying different ones. It can be just an Eclipse issue, but at least I could display Burmese characters in my environment (Linux, Eclipse).

Comment: @Kayaman the result same on text file ! it still contains 'squares'. I used PrintWriter to write file.

Comment: @user1798028 I told you to write the **bytes** in the file, not characters. That means `OutputStream`, not `Writer`.

Comment: @Kayaman I used outputStream and It is same.. so the problem is inputstream ?

Comment: @user1798028 What encodings did you try with the file? Do you know how to write bytes in a file? What editor did you use to open the file?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel can you please write your first comment as answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't Java, the font used by Eclipse doesn't have the glyphs to display those characters, and therefor defaults to a square. You should check the font configuration of Eclipse, maybe you can select a different font that has full unicode support.